# S3 PHP SDK Error undefined method error

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to list the files in my S3 bucket but I keep getting a PHP Error when running this code:

```
require_once './S3.php';

define('awsAccessKey', 'xxx');
define('awsSecretKey', 'xxx');
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
$objects = $s3->list_objects("BUCKETNAME",array("max-keys"=>5));
foreach ($objects->body->Contents as $item){
    print_r($item->Key."");
}
```

I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method S3::list_objects()
```

Google isn't helping me. I can put files in my bucket but I can't list them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious answer is that the (third-party; not from Amazon) `S3` class doesn't have a `list_objects()` method.

This class does, however, have a [`getBucket()`](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#getBucket) method that probably does the same thing.

If you meant to use the official AWS SDK for PHP 1.x, you'd look at the [`AmazonS3::list_objects()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/list_objects) method.

If you want to use something current and supported (i.e., AWS SDK for PHP 2.x), you'd look at the [`S3Client::listObjects()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listObjects) method.

Answer (score 0):

Am using this library https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php. A properly maintained source.

The function you are looking for can be called as `S3->listObjects()` using this library